# Rails - Optimizing the queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do a simple operation but facing unnecessary queries made. I wanted to know how to optimize. In my code snippet, below, the line 2 gets all the users. The "numbers" parameters also has few numbers that aren't in my system. So I need to do an operation to find both exists and non-exists. But Line2 and Line4 are making multiple queries. Any ways to optimize it?

```
  def sync_fit!(numbers, current_user)
    contacts = User.where(number: numbers)
    numbers.each do |number|
      user = contacts.find_by(number: number)
      if user.present?
        # Another operation
      end
    end
  end
```

EDIT 1:

## Table name: users

```
    #  id                     :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
    #  country                :string(255)      not null
    #  number                 :string(255)      not null
    #  first_name             :string(255)      default("")
    #  last_name              :string(255)      default("")
    #  username               :string(255)
    #  email                  :string(255)
```

There is no relation. Only User model is used.

Comment: Show full model relations.

Comment: @Зелёный I added the model details

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there anyway I can get everything and do a filter on ruby side rather than doing on db side?

Yes, you can use [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by):

```
def sync_fit!(numbers, current_user)
  contacts = User.where(number: numbers).group_by(&:number)
  numbers.each do |number|
    # contacts is {number1=>[user1, ...], number2=>[...]}
    user = contacts[number].first # or other logic when many users with same number
    if user
      # Operation with `user`
    end
    # Operation with `number`
  end
end
```

Note: if you don't need to process exactly each number (# Operation with number), you can simplify your code to:

```
def sync_fit!(numbers, current_user)
  contacts = User.where(number: numbers)
  contacts.each do |user|
    number = user.number
    # Operation with `user`
  end
end
```

**UPD:** Fixed `#group_by` example with @johan-wentholt comment.

Comment: How to deal with numbers what aren't in db? __has few numbers that aren't in my system__

Comment: Line "# Operation with `number`"

Comment: Keep in mind that `Enumerable#group_by` creates a group. This means that `contacts[number]` returns a collection and not one user.

Answer (score 1):

The following code executes only one query and works further from there:

```
def sync_fit!(numbers, current_user)
  contacts = User.where(number: numbers)
  unfound_numbers = numbers - contacts.map(&:number)

  contacts.each do |user|
    # code for found users
  end

  unfound_numbers.each do |number|
    # code for numbers not found in users table
  end
end
```

**Note:**

This however assumes you `numbers` input matches the type of the `user.number` output. Assuming `user.number` is an integer than it will loop over all provided numbers, even if found, if a list of string numbers is given eg. `%w[1 2 3 4]`. If you want the extra security make sure the result of `number` and the provided numbers are the same type. `numbers.map(&:to_i)`

You also would normally use `contacts.pluck(:number)` to get the list of numbers. But since you'll use the contacts instances anyway I opted for `map` instead, because this loads the instances and works from there. Resulting in one less query to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can just neglect the line no 2 i.e

`contacts = User.where(number: numbers)`

And on line no 4 do this

`user = User.find_by(number: number)`.

But keep in mind that find_by will return you only single result.

Comment: Then that's my problem again. I might have nearly 100 - 1000 numbers. Isn't there anyway I can get everything and do a filter on ruby side rather than doing on db side? Making the line 4, a ruby part? You have any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `find_by` use `find` method.

```
user = contacts.find(number: number)
```

`find` is handled in Ruby level. `find_by` will send db query

Comment: You're wrong `find` and `find_by` generate sql query in this case.

Comment: `s/find/detect/`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, you may find the Ruby `Array#select` method helpful (not to be confused with the Active Record method of the same name). It accepts a block which should map array elements into Boolean values, and filters the array to those that return `true`. E.g.

```
[0,1,2,3].select {|x| x%2 == 0 }
# [0,2]
```

So your code could would require the minimal change:

```
  def sync_fit!(numbers, current_user)
    contacts = User.where(number: numbers)
    numbers.each do |number|
      users = contacts.select{|contact| contact.number == number }
      if user.present?
        # Another operation
      end
    end
  end
```

This is 'at the ruby level'. However, the fact that contacts is an ActiveRecord relation might cause further queries. As you have no further relations to query against, you can prevent this by making sure that the contacts are fully loaded as ruby objects before proceeding:

```
contacts = User.where(number: numbers).to_a
```

should do the trick.
Note that this approach is probably the closest to your existing code that will accomplish what you want. However, depending on what "another operation" is, you may or may not find one of the other answers more efficient.

Comment: As a note `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#select` is the method being called it just so happens that with a block it delegates to `to_a.select`. Other notes: `select` will return an `Array` where as `find_by` will return a single instance; `user` is not a defined local variable only `users` is

Answer (score 0):

`find_by` is a query method, thus the query fires at line 4. You can achieve the same with `Enumerable#find` since the data is already loaded and no queries will execute in the loop

```
def sync_fit!(numbers, current_user)
  contacts = User.where(number: numbers)
  numbers.each do |number|
    user = contacts.find { |c| c.number == number } 
    if user.present?
      # Another operation
    end
  end
end
```

However in both cases if a `User` shares a number with another `User` only the first will be returned. Additionally you could change the loop to

```
def sync_fit!(numbers, current_user)
  numbers = numbers.dup 
  User.where(number: numbers).each do |contact|
    number = numbers.delete(contact.number)
    # Another operation
  end
end
```

In this case we loop all the `Users` that were located and remove the found numbers from the local variable `numbers`. When the loop completes all the numbers that were not associated with a user will be left in `numbers`

Answer (score 0):

```
def sync_fit!(numbers, current_user)
  contacts = User.where(number: numbers).to_a
  numbers.each do |number|
    user = contacts.find {|contact| contact.number == number}
    if user.present?
      # Another operation
    end
  end
end
```

In line 2, you get all the users, but what you actually get and store in the variable `contacts` is an ActiveRecord relation.  If you want to do the query on line 2, and not make any more queries, covert the ActiveRecord relation into an array and do array operations on the result.